# Rectangle is showing after clicking on text or checkbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I have a window application that has some checkboxes. These checkboxes has a image and appearance is set to button.

My problem is when I click on checkbox, a rectangle appears around the checkbox as shown below. I am not getting what property should I set for avoiding this rectangle.

[image]

```
this.chkboxReportSelect.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;
this.chkboxReportSelect.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(215)))), ((int)(((byte)(221)))), ((int)(((byte)(228)))));
this.chkboxReportSelect.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(215)))), ((int)(((byte)(221)))), ((int)(((byte)(228)))));
this.chkboxReportSelect.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
this.chkboxReportSelect.FlatAppearance.CheckedBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.chkboxReportSelect.FlatAppearance.MouseDownBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.chkboxReportSelect.FlatAppearance.MouseOverBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
this.chkboxReportSelect.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
this.chkboxReportSelect.Image = global::M3.AKFRW.UI.Properties.Resources.checkmark;
this.chkboxReportSelect.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(3, 3);
this.chkboxReportSelect.Name = "chkboxReportSelect";
this.chkboxReportSelect.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(124, 24);
this.chkboxReportSelect.TabIndex = 27;
this.chkboxReportSelect.Text = "Select Report ";
this.chkboxReportSelect.TextImageRelation = System.Windows.Forms.TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText;
this.chkboxReportSelect.UseCompatibleTextRendering = true;
this.chkboxReportSelect.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
```

Comment: What is that control is it actually a `Button`?

Comment: It is a checkbox but its appearance is set to button..

Comment: I checked this code without image, it works fine. I suspect something may be in `Image`; or check your events for that checkbox. may be some event changing the properties in runtime

Answer (score 1):

I assue you are using `FlatStyle`. Rectangle you see is the FlatStyle's border, you can get rid of it by setting `BorderSize` of `FlatAppearance` to `0`

```
checkbox.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
```

Comment: I have already set to 0 to this property but it still displaying border.

Comment: Then pls post code to reproduce the problem, otherwise we'll have to guess

Comment: I have find out the cause of this rectangle appearing.In OS Control Panel we have a property named "Ease of Access Center >> Make the keyboard easier to use >> underline keyboard shortcut and access keys". Check true this property and this problem occuring.